# How can I delete the feature within a feature class with the largest area using cursor and arcpy?

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop, arcpy

I am trying to delete the feature within a polygon shapefile that has the largest area. I have a column in the attribute table with the areas, and can generate a variable with the max area. But I am not able to pass this variable into a loop to delete the feature using cursor.

When I insert the actual number (rather than the variable) into the script, it works fine. But, I cannot get the loop to recognize the variable "y" below.

```
import arcpy
fc = "test.shp"
cursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ["TEST"])
x = max(cursor)
y = int(x[0])
for row in cursor:
   if row[0]==y: 
        cursor.deleteRow()
del row
del cursor
```

I expect this code to delete the one feature in the shapefile with the largest area, but it seems like the variable is not getting passed into the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a separate cursor to get your max. See sample below.

```
import arcpy
fc = "test.shp"
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ['Test']) as cursor:
    x = max(cursor) 
y = int(x[0]) 

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ['Test']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor: 
       if row[0]==y:  
            cursor.deleteRow()
```

Where possible I would avoid using cursors altogether.  You can delete your features like this once you have your max:

```
criteria =  "Test = " + str(y)  
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management  (fc, "DeleteRows",criteria)   
arcpy.DeleteRows_management ("DeleteRows")
```

Be aware that the code as written either way will delete ALL features with the maximum value, not just the first one.